# Reference request for certain kinds of FC-groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

This reference request has a general part and a specific part. In both cases, it feels like I could make faster progress in searching the literature or reconstructing arguments, if I knew the correct terminology to search for or the correct papers/books to use as jumping-off points. (I am not a group theorist, geometric or otherwise, and my own undergraduate education in group theory largely confined itself to the finite setting.)$\newcommand{\cF}{{\mathcal F}}$

---

Some current work my collaborators and I are doing on Fourier algebras of virtually abelian groups has led me, while playing with various toy examples, to consider the family $\cF$ of finitely generated groups in which the centre has finite index. By old results of B. H. Neumann (with precursors in work of Schur and Baer, apparently), the family $\cF$ admits various alternative characterizations:

> **Theorem** (various, but mostly Baer and B. H. Neumann + follklore?)
>   Let $G$ be an infinite, finitely generated group. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1) $Z(G)$ has finite index in $G$;
>
> 2) There is a free abelian, finite-rank subgroup $N\leq Z(G)$ which has finite index in $G$;
>
> 3) There is an injective homomorphism $G\to {\mathbb Z}^d \times F$ for some $d\in {\mathbb N}$ and some finite group $F$;
>
> 4) The derived subgroup $G'$ is finite;
>
> 5) Every conjugacy class in $G$ is finite.

(Condition 1 is sometimes known as FZ; Condition 4 is sometimes known as FD; and Condition 5 is usually known as FC. Note that most of these equivalences fail in at least one direction if we drop the condition of being finitely generated.)

It follows from Neumann's proof (Proc LMS 1951) that if $G\in \cF$ then the set $G_{\rm tor}$ of torsion elements forms a finite subgroup of $G$, which contains $G'$.

**Q1.** Has there been a systematic study of those $G\in\cF$ where $G_{\rm tor}$ is abelian (but $G$ is not)? Is there a name for this class of groups?

Having failed to look up examples of groups satisfying the condition in Q1, some playing around led me to the following example which must surely be known in a more general/systematic context:

**Example.** Let $S= \{\pm 1\}\times {\mathbb Z}^2$ and consider the following bijections on $S$:

$$  a: ( \pm 1, x, y ) \mapsto ( \pm (-1)^y , x+1, y) $$
$$ b: (\pm 1, x,y) \mapsto (\pm 1, x, y+1) $$
$$ t: (\pm 1, x,y) \mapsto (\mp 1, x,y) $$

Informally $b$ is just vertical translation, while $a$ acts as horizontal translation on even rows and as a "glide reflection" on odd rows.

Clearly $t$ commutes with both $a$ and $b$, while some elementary calculations show that $[a,b]=t$. It follows that if we let $G$ be the group generated by $a$ and $b$, then $G$ is finitely generated with derived subgroup $\langle t \rangle$, and $G/G'$ is free abelian of rank $2$. Some more calculations indicate that $G_{\rm tor}=\langle t \rangle$ and so $G$ has no nonabelian finite subgroups. We also have $Z(G) = \langle a^2, b^2, t\rangle$ and so $G/Z(G)$ has order $4$, hence is also abelian.

**Q2.** Is this group $G$ a particular case of some well-known family of 2-step nilpotent groups? More specifically, have groups with the presentation
$$
G_n = \langle a, b \mid [a,b]^n= [a,[a,b] ] =  [b, [a,b] ] = e\rangle
$$
been studied? 
(**EDIT:** blunder/typo in the original presentation pointed out by Mark Sapir; now fixed.)

(**UPDATE:** Yves Cornulier has pointed out in comments that the groups in Q2 are $H_3({\mathbb Z})$ modulo the appropriate finite-index subgroup of the centre, so Q2 is answered to all intents and purposes; I'm leaving it up here for the record.)

Comment: The way it is written, the group in Q2 is free Abelian of rank 2. Yes, this group has been extensively studied.

Comment: Q1: it's easy to produce non-abelian f.g. FC-groups whose torsion subgroup is abelian. Maybe the simplest is to take $C_3\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$ where the generator of $\mathbf{Z}$ acts by inversion on the cyclic group $C_3$. In general, the groups $C_n\rtimes_m\mathbf{Z}$ (where the positive generator of $\mathbf{Z}$ acts by multiplication by $m$ coprime to $n$) are well-known: they provide examples of non-isomorphic residually finite groups with isomorphic profinite completion, for instance for $(n,m)=(11,4)$ vs $(n,m)=(11,9)$.

Comment: @MarkSapir Quite right; I shall correct the blunder/typo. I meant that the commutator of the generators is central and has order $n$

Comment: @YCor Thanks, that's a good point; for some reason I was hung up on trying to get ${\bf Z}^2$ as a quotient. Well the examples you point out will also serve our purposes well. I'd still be interested to know more about the groups in Q2 (now that the typo has been corrected)

Comment: This is the Heisenberg group over $\mathbf{Z}$ modulo the index $n$ subgroup of its center.